# Why is out channels in pyg autoencoder set to 16?

Tags: autoencoder, dimensions, pytorch-geometric

[pytorch_geometric/examples
/autoencoder.py](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/blob/master/examples/autoencoder.py) hardcodes the outchannel to 16 the line reads:

`in_channels, out_channels = dataset.num_features, 16`

possible datasets for this file are 'Cora', 'CiteSeer', 'PubMed' is the assignment of out_channels the number of predictions based on the number of labels? If the dataset had binary labels, should out_channels be 2?

Comment: According this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02907.pdf) it’s equated to some number of features. But is it the edge, the  node orcombination of the two?